# Idle RAM usage increased from 144MB to 510 MB after upgrade to MySQL v5.5.16

Tags: linux, mysql, centos, web-server, memory

So I am on a pretty tight budget (like a lot of folks) and I have a VPS running using Centos v6.0 x86. It has 1024 MB of RAM. I have Apache 2 and MySQL running. I recently upgraded to the latest version of MySQL and after restarting found that my RAM usage went from 14% to 48%. I only have 1024 MB of RAM installed in the VPS but thought that would be enough. Is it normal to see this amount RAM usage even without any traffic? Thanks.

Comment: What are the exact MySQL version numbers before and after the upgrade?

Comment: Currently running MySQL v5.5.16. Previously I was running the default version of MySQL that comes with CentOS v6.0 x86. I am sorry, I do not recall the version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage pattern determines what you need, and you haven't told us anything about that. For example, my personal VPS server has been running for several years with a mere 64MB of RAM. You can bet that's at 100% utilization all the time. It's still very responsive. I answered a question yesterday for somebody who was running with 256MB: [Server hitting high loads and becoming very slow](https://serverfault.com/questions/322771/server-hitting-high-loads-and-becoming-very-slow/322775#322775). His configuration was just using more processes than needed.

You don't detail what memory usage you're talking about either... is idle free memory, or is it free + cache? Remember that MySQL has settings which will determine consumption of real system RAM.

If you're having regular idle time, 1G of memory may be far more than you need.

Comment: I was planning to installing Wordpress and running a family blog. I am afraid I am very new to Linux and I do not know how to separate out free + cache. I am only going by the VPS "control panel" to determine memory usage. If you give me some commands I can run them and get back with some data.

Comment: 256MB is more than enough for a small Wordpress install. I think what you're seeing through the control panel includes the cache usage. A lot of data would have been read form disk in the process of updating, and I strongly presume that is showing as utilization. Take a look at that other question I referenced. I don't know what you're paying now, but I've found a personal love for EC2 micro instances.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I appreciate the insight. I am paying about $10/month now for 1.6 Ghz and 1024 RAM. Besides the Family blog I also wanted to create some virtual sites for testing Drupal, Moodles etc .. Sort of a "learning" project for me to get familiar with Linux. Thanks for the suggestion of EC2 .. I will look at those.

Comment: @webworm Sounds like a good price, and a good way to learn. I'd be happy to help you learn in any way I can.